# QFileDialog getSaveFileName crashes the program

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfiledialog

I use qt file dialog to get the path to save the output file but it crashes or hangs or breaks the programs design or or 
this is my simple use :

```
QString save_file = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"choose a path to save the file","",
                                         "executable files (*.exe)");
```

However I can use QFileDialog getOpenFileName very usually without any problem and with same way :

```
icon_path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"choose an icon","",
                                         "ico and image files (*.ico *.xpm *.jpg *.jpeg *.png);;all files (*)");
```

I'm using qt 4.8 and can't upgrade for the current project
Is the problem in qt library or in my usage or in what ?

Comment: I have tried with Qt4 4.8.7 and it works correctly, if you want help it provides a [mcve] since for me the error is in another side.

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using the QFileDialog::getSaveFileName in a background thread but gui elements are only valid in the main gui thread . I think they should write this in a big bold text in the first of the beginners documentation

Comment: The documentation is for everyone, not only for beginners, in the documentation about threads we talk about it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: I meant this https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners however the link you provided is very useful . thanks

Comment: use threads you can say it's an intermediate knowledge so I do not expect this in those examples